# Laravel is incorrectly matching strings in the database with numbers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My database has a table containing warehouse locations.

These can be numbers and a mix of numbers and letters. For example:

- 110
- 11A3

These are both stored in a VARCHAR type column.

If I use the query builder to try and find a record with the value 11E1, then it will match with the 110 number, rather than fail.

```
DB::table('locations')->where('value', '11E1')->first();
```

Presumably, this is because of how MYSQL treats scientific notation, but how do I disable this so that it only finds the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. My database connection was not running in strict mode.

In config/database.php make sure you have strict set to **true**